# How to add custom image background to span inside bootstrap button?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to use custom icon as background image inside span for a bootstrap toggle button. Is it possible to achieve it without using fontawesome or glyphicons?

CSS:

```
.icon-search {
    background-image: url("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/23295105/search.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
}
```

HTML:

```
<button class="toggle">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-search"></span>
</button>
```

Here's my fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/ox04anfb/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add this to your css

```
width: 20px; // replace with actual width
height: 20px; // replace with actual height
display: inline-block;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the solution of QED, but add the auto property:

```
width: auto; // replace with actual width
height: auto; // replace with actual height
display: inline-block;
```